# How to get live stream sharable CDN link using agora-sdk ng

Tags: agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

Created angular project using agora sdk ng

tried to push my live stream using agora it throw me berlow error

> **reason: "Publish error on rtmp-publish"
> status: 32
> type: "liveStreamingFailed"
> url: "rtmp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov"**

Agular side code:

> **this.client.startLiveStreaming("rtmp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov",false);**

Please help on my above issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The `startLiveStreaming` method is meant to push the Agora stream to an extertnal RTMP server, such as pushing your stream to YouTube Live or Twitch.

To inject media from an RTMP url, you should use `addInjectStreamUrl`([API reference](https://docs.agora.io/en/Voice/API%20Reference/web_ng/interfaces/iagorartcclient.html#addinjectstreamurl))

From the documentation:

> Injects an online media stream to a live-broadcast channel.
>
> After you call this method, the server pulls the online stream and
> injects it into a live-broadcast channel. This is applicable to
> scenarios where all audience members in the channel can watch a live
> show and interact with each other. See Inject Online Media Stream for
> details.
>
> If the online media stream is injected successfully, this stream is
> added to the channel, and all users in the channel receive the
> AgoraRTCClient.on("user-published") and
> AgoraRTCClient.on("user-joined") callbacks with the uid 666.